# Need to parse a binary string which is invalid in UTF8

Tags: elixir

I have html data returned by this:

```
case HTTPoison.get("some url") do
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
    IO.binwrite(body)
```

Which actually is invalid utf-8 data because this prints it out as a binary string:

```
  # 1
  IO.puts(body) #prints binary data <<111, 222, 333....>>

  # 2
  {:ok, file} = File.open("hello.txt", [:write])
  IO.binwrite(file, body)
  {:ok, data} = File.read("hello.txt")
  bb = :erlang.binary_to_list(data)
  IO.binwrite(bb) #prints binary data [111, 222, 333....]
```

When I open the file, I can read it and it's a text file. But it prints in binary and this says it's invalid:

```
  IO.puts(String.valid?(body)) #false
```

**My ultimate goal** is parse "body" -- find and extract substrings. How can I do that if it's in binary?

Comment: Most `String` functions will work fine with that. `String.contains?(<<250, 251, 252>>, <<252>>) #=> true` even though that's not valid according to `String.valid?`.

Comment: @Dogbert, I'd like to use strings in String.contains. Or binary as a source string and a string as what to find. `String.contains?(<<250, 251, 252>>, "what to find")`

Comment: That would also work. Try `String.contains?(body, "some string that actually exists in the file")`. The thing I think I've not clearly said yet is that Strings are the same data type internally as binaries. Elixir just doesn't print them as actual text if it contains any invalid UTF8 sequence.

Comment: @Dogbert, that works, tnx. How can I find a substring which starts with "aaa" and is of length 5? I know of "String.slice" only and can't find anything more appropriate.

Comment: Try Regular Expressions: `Regex.scan(body, ~r/aaa../)`.

Comment: @Dogbert, thanks......

Comment: What is the `content-type` of your HTTPoison response? Also, have you tried: `inspect(body, binaries: :as_strings)` to get a feel of your response in the string format?